# Uploading CodeIgniter to a live server (Hostpapa)

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, web

I am having trouble putting my codeigniter project live into a subdomain. First I had a 404 error page not found, which I think I resolved by trying to change the path of both my application and system folders. The latter now became my problem as it returns the error "**Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php**". I've done my research and after uploading the whole project, I realized that I have to edit something inside index.php, as well as in the config.php under the application folder. I am not sure if htaccess has to do with my problem. After the uploading the whole codeigniter project, the folders in my file manager is structured as follows. The (home/dir) is my home directory and under that is the public_html folder (www). Then, under that I have a subdomain called login, which where I uploaded my codeigniter project. The application and system folders are there.

The only thing I changed in the index.php file is the values of the variables $application_folder and $system_path. By default, their values where set to just application and system respectively. Now I changed it to the following:

```
$application_folder = '/home/dir/www/stack-it.ca/login/application';
$system_path = '/home/dir/www/stack-it.ca/login/system';
```

I still get the same error that I mentioned earlier. If it is any help here is what my htaccess file looks like. This is located in the same level of the application and system folders.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I tried editing the files I know that must edited in order for Hostpapa to host my codeigniter project. Am I missing something? Should I do another step?

Comment: is at least the home page loading?

Comment: yes it is loading properly

Comment: could you give me any url of example that is not loading?

Comment: when i type in stack-it.ca/login this error shows up. Your application folder path does not appear to be set correctly. Please open the following file and correct this: index.php

Comment: what permissions do you have at your app?

Comment: what do you mean by permissions? is it a file or something?

Comment: permissions over the files, to write, read and modify

Comment: most of the permissions are to write, read ad modify.There's no write in the Group and World section.